# protect (encrypt) password in the web.config file (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net

```
 <system.net>
  <mailSettings>
   <smtp from="email@domain.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
    <network clientDomain="www.domain.com" host="smtp.live.com" defaultCredentials="false" port="25" userName=" email@domain.com " password="password" enableSsl="true" />
   </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
 </system.net>
```

This is the case where I need encryption for my password. I searched and googled much on the web but I can’t be able to encrypt anymore.

Can anyone help me do this in a simple but secure way.

Comment: You can move secrets out of web.config file. See http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/best-practices-for-deploying-passwords-and-other-sensitive-data-to-aspnet-and-azure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote an article about that on my blog: http://pvlerick.github.io/2009/03/encrypt-appconfig-section-using-powershell-as-a-post-build-event

My idea was that you want the password to be clear in the IDE, but encrypted in the output folder's web.config/app.config.

The script is

```
param(
  [String] $appPath = $(throw "Application exe file path is mandatory"),
  [String] $sectionName = $(throw "Configuration section is mandatory"),
  [String] $dataProtectionProvider = "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider"
)

#The System.Configuration assembly must be loaded
$configurationAssembly = "System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
[void] [Reflection.Assembly]::Load($configurationAssembly)

Write-Host "Encrypting configuration section..."

$configuration = [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager]::OpenExeConfiguration($appPath)
$section = $configuration.GetSection($sectionName)

if (-not $section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
{
  $section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection($dataProtectionProvider);
  $section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = [System.Boolean]::True;
  $configuration.Save([System.Configuration.ConfigurationSaveMode]::Modified);
}

Write-Host "Succeeded!"
```

The post-build command is

```
powershell "& ""C:\Documents and Settings\VlericP\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\EncryptAppConfigSection.ps1""" '$(TargetPath)' 'connectionStrings'
```

Comment: I know it's been 4 years since this post was added, but I'll try my chances. I'm using VS2013/C#; I created EncryptAppConfigSection.ps1 and added it to "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0", then added "powershell "& ""C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\EncryptAppConfigSection.ps1""" '$(TargetPath)' 'connectionStrings'" to post-build events, but I get error on build: The command exited with code 1.
Can you help me to know how to fix this?? I'm clueless about powershell scripts!

Comment: I added a question about this answer. If you can help me please check it. Thanks.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27302737/error-in-powershell-post-build-event-to-secure-app-config-file-in-my-net-winfor

Answer (score 3):

This is another way to encrypt and decrypt coonection string check it if you are using vs2010 then open vs2010 with run as administrator

```
string provider = "RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider"; 


string section = "connectionStrings";  

protected void btnEncrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  

{ 

   Configuration confg = 
   WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath); 

   ConfigurationSection configSect = confg.GetSection(section); 

   if (configSect != null) 

   { 
      configSect.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(provider); 
      confg.Save(); 

   } 

} 
protected void btnDecrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    Configuration config = 
        WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath); 
    ConfigurationSection configSect = config.GetSection(section); 
    if (configSect.SectionInformation.IsProtected) 
    { 
        configSect.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection(); 
        config.Save(); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a thread on ASP.NET forums that has some brainstorming going on and provide a few possible solutions:

[How to encrypt the SMTP Node in web.config](http://forums.asp.net/p/1537458/3738598.aspx)