# .Net How do I secure passwords in multiple configs

Tags: .net, security, encryption

I have several applications (web sites, windows services) installed on a workstation with plain passwords stored in their config files (password to database, password to external service e.t.c).

I'd like to make my passwords unreadable in configuration file, keeping other configuration tags readable at the same time.

I'm about using some encryption algorythm (MD5, Rijndael) with parameters stored in `Machine.config`. Is it the best practice?

How shall I protect my passwords if malefactor will gain workstation administrative rights?

Answer (score 2):

This answer:

[protect (encrypt) password in the web.config file (asp.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525515/protect-encrypt-password-in-the-web-config-file-asp-net)

references a technique for encrypting passwords in configuration files here:

http://www.pvle.be/2009/03/encrypt-appconfig-section-using-powershell-as-a-post-build-event/

that works a treat (it uses Powershell as a post-build step).

---

However, if an evildoer gets workstation admin rights then you should assume that *nothing* is safe on your PC. So if this is genuinely an issue you'll want to consider having passwords on removeable media or similar so they're physically unreachable if you're not at the PC.

The script I've referenced could be modified to pull the password from that removeable media at the encryption stage.

Comment: +1 for the comment that once they have workstation access you are ****ed. I'm not even sure that removable media is an option since the service/website needs to be able to access them (at startup at least) and I would imagine you don't want somebody physically present to stick your media in every time it needs to start up...

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to create a class to encrypt the password then save this password in the configuration files then create a util class that contains the the key to encrypt the passwords hard coded in the class and use it to decrept the password.