# Encrypting only Passwords in web.config ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, encryption, web-config

How can I encrypt only passwords in a web.config file?

```
<add name="PSystem" connectionString="Server=test;Database=Dev;User ID=testuser;Password=password@123;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525515/protect-encrypt-password-in-the-web-config-file-asp-net

Comment: Just move them out of the web.config file. See http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/best-practices-for-deploying-passwords-and-other-sensitive-data-to-aspnet-and-azure

Answer (score 2):

I believe that built-in encryption mechanisms work on the entire connectionString section:

[See this website for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx0f3cf2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

If you would like to encrypt in-memory passwords, maybe entered by the user through a login form, you could use [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx)

Comment: Hi, instead of entire connection string is it possible to encrypt only passwords?

Comment: As I mentioned before built-in tools allow you to do this on the entire section. You could accomplish what you need by encrypting the password using your own method and then decrypting it within your app when it starts or just before using it for a DB connection.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using flags in the connecction string as follows:

```
<add name="PSystem" 
 connectionString="Server=test;
                   Database=Dev;
                   User ID=@UserID@;
                   Password=#Password#;
                   Trusted_Connection=False;
                   Encrypt=True;" 
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

then you can have the encrypted user and password as follows:

```
<add key="DB_User" value = [Encrypted Username]>
<add key="DB_Password" value = [Encrypted Password]>
```

Then in code you just replace the flags:

```
string _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PSystem"].ConnectionString;

string user = Decrypt(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DB_User"]);
string password = Decrypt(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DB_Password"]);

_connectionString = _connectionString.Replace("##User##", user).Replace("##Password##", password);
```

Answer (score 1):

> To encrypt configuration file
>   contents, use the Aspnet_regiis.exe tool with the –pe option and the
>   name of the configuration element to be encrypted.
>
> aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/SampleApplication" -prov
>   "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy(v=vs.100).aspx